# How to user to upload own data/external data for visualisation D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I would like the user to be able to upload their own data( in a format that I will approve) and the graphs that I have process that data and the data be visualized. Anyone have an example of this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your question is rather broad.. Are you trying to upload a json file or csv file or something?

Comment: You'll have to code serverside endpoint for that, which would accept form with multipart file, validate against your format, save it somewhere, and return as a response from your (e.g.) rest controller, which you'd request from js

Comment: @wentjun csv file.